Javascript Test File giving JSDOM TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
I have a VanillaJS project that has a test.js file. While running the file, it is giving me this error
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
        at Function.getPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)

      1 | import {fireEvent, getByTestId} from "@testing-library/dom"
      2 | import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect"
    > 3 | import jsdom, {JSDOM} from "jsdom"
        | ^
      4 | import path from "path"
      5 |
      6 | const BASE = path.resolve(__dirname, "../src");

      at Object.getPrototypeOf (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/utils.js:34:39)
      at Object.require (node_modules/jsdom/lib/api.js:11:18)

This was not happening a week ago I guess. It started showing up randomly. Here is a portion of test file that is getting executed.
import {fireEvent, getByTestId} from "@testing-library/dom"
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect"
import jsdom, {JSDOM} from "jsdom"
import path from "path"

const BASE = path.resolve(__dirname, "../src");

let virtualConsole
let dom, body

describe("stack operation test", function () {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    virtualConsole = new jsdom.VirtualConsole();
    virtualConsole.on("error", console.error);
    dom = await JSDOM.fromFile(`${BASE}/index.html`, {
      runScripts: "dangerously",
      resources: "usable",
      pretendToBeVisual: true,
      virtualConsole
    })
    await loadDom(dom)
    body = dom.window.document.body
  })

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.spyOn(dom.window, 'alert').mockImplementation(() => {
    })
  })

  it("Clicking on the push button should push the item to the bottom of the stack board", async function () {
    const input = getByTestId(body, "input")
    await typeText(input, "item1")
....
....
....
....

For reference, here is the package.json and jest.config.json
 "scripts": {
    "prestart": "npm install",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "pretest": "npm install && npm run build",
    "start": "node app.js",
    "test": "jest --ci --testResultsProcessor=jest-junit"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.21.5",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^9.2.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "babel-jest": "^29.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "jest-junit": "^16.0.0",
    "jsdom": "^22.0.0",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack": "^5.82.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.0.4",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^6.1.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.25.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.18.2",
    "h8k-components": "^1.0.0",
    "h8k-design": "^1.0.16",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.5.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.11"
  }

module.exports = {
    clearMocks: true,
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['regenerator-runtime/runtime'],
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
        "/node_modules/(?!(jsdom)/)",
    ],
    testPathIgnorePatterns: [
        "/node_modules/",
    ],
    useStderr: true
};


FYI: I have tried upgrading the version of JSDOM, it is not working.

"This was not happening a week ago I guess. It started showing up randomly" -- do you have any idea of what changed? Packages, environment, code? Are you using git and have a snapshot from the last working commit you can diff against?

Your error happens inside node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/utils.js on that line:
const AsyncIteratorPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(async function* () {}).prototype);

I may assume that the file is transpiled somehow (i see babel-jest in the deps and also transformIgnorePatterns). async function(){}* is replaced with some polyfill function but this polyfill function is not provided so it is undefined. I would recommend to check babel config file.
